# Can't pass props like className or style to custom component's props

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I'm working on creating a TypeScript friendly NPM package but I'm having trouble passing common HTML attributes as props like `className` and `style` to my component.  I was hoping to not have to manually add each attribute to my list of props by extending an interface with all the desired props.  My simplified component looks like this:

```js
import React, { Key, ReactElement } from "react";

interface MyComponentProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    customText: string;
    uniqueKey?: Key;
}

export function MyComponent({uniqueKey, customText, ...props}: MyComponentProps): ReactElement {
    return (
        <div key={uniqueKey} {...props}>{customText}</div>
    );
}
```

I created a `uniqueKey` prop since it can't be named just `key` (same with `ref`).  I tried to expand a `props` parameter to pass arbitrary props to my component, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I import this component into my project and try to call it like:

```js
<MyComponent customText="Hello World" uniqueKey={123} className="myClass" />
```

I get the error: `Property 'className' does not exist on type 'MyComponentProps'.`

I was hoping this would work since `MyComponentProps` extends `HTMLAttributes` which has the props I want like `className` and `style`.

My `index.d.ts` file looks like:

```js
import React, { Key, ReactElement } from "react";
interface MyComponentProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
    customText: string;
    uniqueKey?: Key;
}
export declare function MyComponent({ uniqueKey, customText, ...props }: MyComponentProps): ReactElement;
export {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the available props for a specific HTML element is by using `JSX.IntrinsicElements`.

```
type MyComponentProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements['div'] & {
    customText: string;
    uniqueKey?: Key;
}
```

Under the hood, `JSX.IntrinsicElements['div']` is the following type.

```
React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does seem to do the trick!  Could you help me understand why extending `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>` didn't also work for me?  It also appears with your solution that I can eliminate my `uniqueKey` prop and just use `key` when creating an instance of `MyComponent` too.

Comment: `HTMLAnchorElement` is incorrect since you are passing the props to a `div` element.  If you replace it with `HTMLDivElement` it should work although it will be missing the `key` prop.

Comment: Oops, sorry--there was a typo in my original example.  In my real code I am using an anchor element, but in my example above it's a div.  I fixed the typo in my original question.  With that said...why does extending `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>` not work in my given example?  Even though it sounds like you suggested it should work--it didn't unfortunately.  This is an NPM package, when testing my package I could use attributes like `className`, but not in projects that had my NPM package as a dependency.

Comment: Is `@types/react` installed in the project where you are using your package?

Comment: Yes, version 17.0.0

Comment: What does your `.d.ts` file look like for your npm package?  That is where the type definitions for your component will be pulled from, so that will help me figure this out.

Comment: I've updated the original question with what the `index.d.ts` file looks like before your suggested change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226450/discussion-between-mark-skelton-and-roundtheworld).